# how to authenticate the user with warden/devise without password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

In my app during login, user will provide only email, password is not required.I want to authenticate it using devise/warden.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include ExpireExistingToken

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    resource.update(language: Constant::SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.key(params['locale'])) if params['locale'].present?
    resource.send_otp(force_expire: true) if resource.email_verified?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    flash.delete(:notice)
  end

  def destroy
    session.delete(:is_otp_verified)
    super
  end
end
```

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Responsible for token expiration
module ExpireExistingToken
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :remove_existing_token, only: :new
  end

  protected

  def remove_existing_token
    uuid = session[:uuid]
    usr = User.find_by(uuid: uuid) if uuid
    return unless usr
    usr.send(:clear_reset_password_token)
    usr.save
    session.delete(:uuid)
  end
end
```

I tried to override valid_password? in User model, but it didn't work. Please help me out on this.

Comment: You can manually sign _in the user with `sign_in(user)`.

Comment: Hi @Vishal, I tried to manually sign_in, it is working. I had just one doubt will it have any complications? Actually I am a naive in ROR so please don't mind .

Comment: @Vishal, replaced self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options), with self.resource = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email])

Comment: Nope, There wouldn't be an issue. it depends on your business logic how you wanna do it. For instance, you are signing up without a password, but how will s/he create a password for them?

Comment: ok great, @Vishal after sign_in without password, user will be redirected to verify otp, that will be sent on his mail. User will never require to create password.

Comment: `sign_in`  will set the cookie for that user. In your case, the sign_in method should call once the user enters the correct OTP.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot @Vishal.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to override `Devise` password required validation method and return `false` during save. If you want to disable it only for resource or functionality specific, you need to send `virtual attribute` from form during save.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_validation  

  protected

  def password_required?
    return false if skip_validation
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried the above solution, but it didn't work. warden.authenticate!(auth_options), always returns 401 unauthorized access. Even after overriding password_required? method.

Answer (score 0):

In Sinatra with Warden use [`set_user`](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/blob/v1.2.9/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L170):

```
post '/sign_up' do
  user = PgUser.new(id, pg_connection)
  env['warden'].set_user(user)
  redirect '/'
end
```